# Is this a standard soap authentication request?

Tags: java, spring, authentication, soap

Below SOAP authentiation request returns a session id which is used for subsequent requests :

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:com.test">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:login>
         <urn:credential>
            <urn:companyId>?</urn:companyId>
            <urn:username>?</urn:username>
            <urn:password>?</urn:password>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <urn:developerKey>?</urn:developerKey>
         </urn:credential>
         <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
         <urn:param>
            <urn:name>?</urn:name>
            <urn:value>?</urn:value>
         </urn:param>
      </urn:login>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Is this related to "Basic access authentication" desribed at : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication ?

Currently I am using SAAJ to create the above request but is there a higher abstraction I should be using ?

Reading about Spring (http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/client.html) and the WebServiceTemplate it does seem to provide an abstraction
for authenticating but I don't know if this can be used to generate above SOAP authentication request?

Comment: There is no such thing as "standart soap authentication request", but there are extensions to it, for example: http://www.whitemesa.com/soapauth.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said by @setec - there is no "standard soap authentication request". Coming down to your example, this is a very implementation specific request (i.e. the provider has requested for very specific tags (in your case urn:username and urn:password).

You can use spring template or any other Web Service tool like Axis 2 or JAX-WS or more to generate the above SOAP request provided it is mentioned properly in the WSDL.

If you need more details on how to access the web service try to search in google or refer to any of the below links:
[Spring Web Service](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/client.html)
[JAX WS tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnayl.html)

Comment: does this not mean that I cannot use http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/UsernamePasswordCredentials.html to create the SOAP request since UsernamePasswordCredentials takes username/password in constructor and does not take companyId as is required in request ?

Comment: that is correct. Please understand that HTTP Basic Authentication - deals with adding the authentication to the HTTP headers. In your case your authentication is added to the SOAP Body (which is passed though the HTTP Body content)